# extract value of data-ref-gdsNo with xpath

Tags: xpath

I am hoping to get the value of data-ref-gdsNo

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="goodsList" data-ref-gdsNo="A00000102552" data-ref-dispCatNo=""  
data-ref-itemNo="001"><span class="tx_brand">abc</a>
```

I had successfully get the link by

```
.//*[@class='goodsList']/@href
```

However when I use

```
.//*[@class='goodsList']/@data-ref-gdsNo
```

It returns no value, how could i fix this to get"A00000102552" ? Thank you

Comment: If you are able to get href, you should also be able to get the data-ref-gdsNo. Share at least part of the xml that you are working on to get answers here.

Comment: I wish so too but it returned no value.. Here is the link and thanks for your help!: http://www.oliveyoung.co.kr/store/main/getBestList.do?dispCatNo=900000100100001&fltDispCatNo=10000010001&pageIdx=1&rowsPerPage=8

Comment: Just now I tried with //a[starts-with(@data-ref-goodsNo, 'A')]/@data-ref-goodsNo on xpath tester, it works only if I add </img> within the script as it shows result Unable to perform XPath operation. The element type "img" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</img>". However I am using import.io so how can i perform it within one line? @SomeDude